# html content overlapping navbar

Tags: css, html

The content from my html document is overlapping my navbar.

I have tried to add margins to my `.main-nav` in css but it did not work.

The example code has "Hello World" on top of my nav bar. I want to have a new section that starts right below the main navbar without using

```css
.main-nav{
  float:right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.main-nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.section-test{
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
      <div class="row">
      <img src="{% static 'resources/img/logo-transparent.png' %}" class="logo" alt=" Logo">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Get a Demo</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

   <section class="section-test">
    <h3>hello world</h3>
   </section>
</body>
```

Comment: i have no idea what you're trying to achieve , can you provide us with a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `clear:both;` on section-test class

```css
/* Styles go here */

.main-nav{
  float:right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.main-nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.section-test{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
        <div class="row">
        <img src="{% static 'resources/img/logo-transparent.png' %}" class="logo" alt=" Logo">
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Get a Demo</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

     <section class="section-test">
      <h3>hello world</h3>
     </section>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `float: right` on your `nav` element, it is out of the flow. What that means is that the `nav` parent doesn't takes it's height into account.

You have multiple solutions here. The first one is to apply an `overflow:hidden` to the nav element to force it to grow, to use a clear element as mentioned by Punith Jain, or simplify your markup and get rid of the floating with the usage of flexbox!

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav{
  text-align: right;
  flex: 1;
}

.main-nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="{% static 'resources/img/logo-transparent.png' %}" class="logo" alt=" Logo">
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Get a Demo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<section>
  <h3>hello world</h3>
</section>
```